# ReSharper doesn't add "<" when completing intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm running into a weird issue with Intellisense in ReSharper and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, where typing a "<" does complete what's selected with Intellisense, but it doesn't add that character afterwards so I end up having to type "<" twice when autocompleting a generic method.  Oddly enough this is the only character that doesn't also get added after the completion, even ">" works, anyone know how to get it to complete and add the open bracket in a single key press?

**UPDATE:**
This is when editing C# with ReSharper version 7.1.3 (C# Edition)

An example of this is: say I have a generic method TestMethod in a TestClass and I type

```
TestClass.Te
```

And then the intellisense popup comes up and gives me "TestMethod".  If I then type a < to complete the method's name and then pass in the type, I get

```
TestClass.TestMethod
```

But I would expect to get

```
TestClass.TestMethod<
```

Notice that it doesn't add the "<" at the end, it only completes the method name.  If I were to type any other character to complete the method, like a "(" it would work and give me

```
TestClass.TestMethod(
```

Effectively both completing the method name and adding the character at the end.  This problem only seems to happen with the "<" character.

Comment: What language is this - HTML, XML, XAML? Also, what version of R# are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, updated the question.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing I'd report as a bug to Resharper. Not a programming problem, per se.

Comment: It may be, just didn't know if there was an obvious setting I was overlooking to fix this or anything of that sort.